# How do I can I keep state in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I currently have a set of automation tasks where we create a new account in every test. However, this is slow. Ideally we would create an account once and then use those details in all other tests, but I'm unsure how to share this state.

I tried using cy.state as that seemed to be related but I couldn't figure it out. Any pointers to a similar setup would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin that can help [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session)
.

> **Setting up, caching, and re-creating the test data using cypress-data-session plugin**
>
> By re-using the expensive-to-create objects like users, projects, etc. you will make your tests much much faster, and potentially the tests will be easier to read and maintain.

**Example user caching**

```js
function registerApi(username, password) {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/register',
    form: true,
    body: {
      username,
      password,
    },
  })
}
cy.dataSession({
  name: 'user',
  setup() {
    registerApi(username, password)
  },
  validate() {
    return cy.task('findUser', username).then(Boolean)
  },
})
loginUser(username, password)
```

Comment: BTW `cy.state()` is the state of the test, not the app